# Pandas groupby count values above threshold

Tags: python, pandas

I have a groupby question that I can't solve. It is probably simple, but I can't get it to work nicely. I am trying to compute some statistics on a variable with pandas groupby chained with the very handy agg function. I would like add to the list below a calculation of the number of values above a given threshold.

```
df = df.groupby(['scenario','Name','year','month'])["Value"].agg([np.min,np.max,np.mean,np.std])
```

Usually, I compute the number of values above a given threshold as shown below, but I can't find a way to add this to the aggregation function. Do you know how I could do that?

```
df =df[df>0].groupby(['scenario','Name','year','month']).count()
```

Comment: can you provide a sample dataset and the matching expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer works.  Else you could add it to the one line, not needing to create a separate function by using `lambda x:` instead.

```
df = df.groupby(["scenario", "Name", "year", "month"])["Value"].agg([np.min, np.max, np.mean, np.std, lambda x: ((x > 0)*1).sum()])
```

The logic here: `(x > 0)` returns True/False bool; `*1` turns the bool to an integer (1 = True, 0 = False); `.sum()` will sum all the 1s and 0s within the group - and as those that are True = 1, the sum will count all values greater than 0.

Running a quick test on the time taken, your solution is faster, but I thought I would give an alternative solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by creating a function and passing it in the agg function.

```
def counta(x):
    m = np.count_nonzero(x > 10)
    return m 

df = df.groupby(['scenario','Name','year','month'])["Value"].agg([np.min,np.max,np.mean,np.std,counta])
```